# Change path directory bash.exe

Tags: bash, shell, windows, pwd

I installed `bash` on my Windows machine, and now when I run the shell, the `pwd` is:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32
```

How may I change this?

I open this shell everyday to work, and the directory when I'm  working is:

```
/mnt/c/Users/[myname]/Desktop/cours/rootMe
```

So, it would be faster if my `pwd` when I'm  running the shell is the great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try editing `~/.bashrc` for it. (Probably `C:\Users\[myname]\.bashrc`)
Append the following line:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/[myname]/Desktop/cours/rootMe
```

More details on executing commands on shell startup - [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

Comment: Good job, it's fine now ! 
Thanks you :D